# What's this weird blue 8-long thin hinge piece?

Tags: part-identification

I've spent several hours on BrickLink now trying to identify this mystery piece. It doesn't have a part number on it, only the Lego logo. It looks kind of like a hinge or something that might snap into a doorway, but I haven't found anything similar. Can you help me?

[image: back side with brick for scale]
[image: front side]

Comment: It kind of looks like a window. Could you snap it in to a window holder?

Comment: The hinge is to large for the snap holes in a standard-sized 4x3 window.  It does snap with pieces like [this](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=15712#T=S&O={}), however.

Comment: Pictures in focus!  That is so amazing.  Kudos to Martin for including high-res in-focus pictures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part [4218 Garage Roller Door Section without Handle](http://rebrickable.com/parts/4218):

[image: 4218]

As you might imagine from the name, these can be connected and used for garage doors as seen in Century Skyway, for example:

[image: 6597]

Comment: Wow! I´m impressed. Thanks so much for your help :-)